# Visual Studio extension: socket communication

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets

I am writing a Visual Studio extension that requires two or more instances of Visual Studio on different machines to communicate.

Before I start using third party libraries or open new socket ports with all the issues involved in managing TCP communication over the internet, is there any in-built communication service available within Visual Studio itself?

Comment: I doubt it. What would be the use case for that?

Comment: the use case is to be able to highlight a method in a file, right-click to open the context menu, select the person to transfer the information to and make a popup appear on the other person's Visual Studio. When they click on it, it takes you to the corresponding line on that workstation. It's a sort of collaboration tool that eases when you say to a team coworker to have a look at a certain line of code basically

Comment: You would need some form of centralised server they log into..

Comment: Sorry, I meant what would be the use case for Microsoft to add that feature to VS!

Comment: @BugFinder I thought that eventually there could be a service like Bonjour that keeps a list of running instances of Visual Studio or something like that. That would have made it a serverless experience. Going the server way would probably be easy though. I can just have the VS clients poll a server somewhere for new messages every now and then or use some sort of pub/sub to keep them updated in realtime.

Comment: @stuartd I am pretty sure Microsoft already has some kind of communication service available within VS and TFS as that would make sense. Of course they probably have no interest in skipping TFS as that's part of their commercial offer. On the other hand it would be handy for small teams that collaborate without a TFS